# CLI has stopped working error after making ODBC PDO persistent

Tags: php, pdo, command-line-interface, php-7, event-viewer

Setting up some tests in PHPUnit/Sublime, and am running into a problem with PDO persistent connection.

When I add `array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true)` to the connection, the tests run OK, and then at the end I get a windows popup that says CLI has stopped working.

If I comment out the persisent directive, tests run ok; but they take a painfully long time establishing a lot of connections with setup, tear down, and lots of db objects.

```
class DB_PDO {

  protected $dsn = 'odbc:DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC DRIVER} *** ';
  protected $user = '***';
  protected $pass = '***';

  public function __construct($dsn='',$user='',$pass='') {
    /* Handle defaults */
    if ("" == $dsn)   $dsn   = $this->dsn;
    if ("" == $user)  $user  = $this->user;
    if ("" == $pass)  $pass  = $this->pass;

    try {

      if(!property_exists($this,'pdo')) {
        // runs fast, but generates cli error
        $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn,$user,$pass, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));

        // runs slowly, but no error
        //$this->pdo = new PDO($dsn,$user,$pass);

        // didn't tell me anything
        //$this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      print "Error! " . $e->getMessage() . "<br>";
      die;
    }

    // snip... 

  }
```

If it's any help,

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.1.3 (cli) (built: Mar 14 2017 23:33:35) ( NTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x64
 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.5.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans
```

The database, however, is on 5.6

---

I'm not sure where to look for the problem, since my only error is a popup in windows. Nothing is echoed to the command line.

---

Requested information:

- Windows 8.1 Enterprise
- <strike>Event Viewer shows no event generated (system log)</strike>
- Not XAMP.  IIS server on another box. I'm testing scripts from local, but scripts are on a different box (using mapped drive).
- Event Viewer shows error in application log (local):

error:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" /> 
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID> 
    <Level>2</Level> 
    <Task>100</Task> 
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-04-03T21:00:11.000000000Z" /> 
    <EventRecordID>60403</EventRecordID> 
    <Channel>Application</Channel> 
    <Computer>--redacted--.LOCAL</Computer> 
    <Security /> 
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>php.exe</Data> 
    <Data>7.1.3.0</Data> 
    <Data>58c87e19</Data> 
    <Data>ntdll.dll</Data> 
    <Data>6.3.9600.18946</Data> 
    <Data>5a9a3a38</Data> 
    <Data>c0000005</Data> 
    <Data>000000000003571c</Data> 
    <Data>1828</Data> 
    <Data>01d3cb8ec02fd590</Data> 
    <Data>C:\php\php.exe</Data> 
    <Data>C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll</Data> 
    <Data>ff51f074-3781-11e8-8288-00155d14e007</Data> 
    <Data /> 
    <Data /> 
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Xampp? Windows 7? Recall a number of issues with php_opcache.dll. Can't get more info from "event viewer"? Not much to go on.

Comment: I'll add to the question.